# ssl_error_bad_cert_domain in firefox, when changed cert domain, works in IE etc

Tags: ssl, certificate

Yesterday I changed my ssl certificate to use a different domain. However, since then firefox believes that my cert is only valid for the old domain. Works properly (with the correct new domain in all other browsers). I tried this from my friends pc and firefox then worked, so seems the error is different depending on where the access is coming from.

I get the following error:

www.mynewdomain.com uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is only valid for www.myolddomain.com.

(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

This error is baffling me. Would love it if someone has an idea of what may be happening?

Could it be that the error is caused by IP's or domains propogating around the internet?

Any help would be much appreciated?

Cheers
K

Comment: You should have given the true names involved and associated certificate...